# Throuble with using SharedArrayBuffer with third party JS

Tags: webassembly, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-opener-policy

I add respone header ("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin") to use SharedArrayBuffer (to support webassembly).  But now I have trouble with adding third party JS in my page, which will be blocked by cross-origin isolated. Any work around method to use third party JS with webassembly ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set only [CORP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)) or [COEP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy) as well?

If you set COEP to require-corp, your script will have to explicitly grant permission using I think the script you are trying to load will have to set [CORP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)) to `cross-origin`

You could also try to set [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) I am not sure if it will override the behavior of the.

CORP protects your resources from being loaded from another origin [cross-origin isolation headers](https://www.snigel.com/blog/a-simple-guide-to-coop-coep-corp-and-cors/), so it should not prevent you from loading scripts (I think).