# how to use (WebAssembly) SharedArrayBuffer, if it will require cross-origin isolation?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, cross-domain, webassembly

I am implementing a web app, using microservices deployed in docker, then to get some data, I need to make requests to each microservices(different ports).

My problem now : is that I need to use WASM to paint in a canvas some information I am getting from a web-socket connection from different socket servers (different ip/port).

I am getting this error:

> SharedArrayBuffer is not defined

Also an explanation that says:

> SharedArrayBuffer will require cross-origin isolation as of M92,
> around July 2021.

But I can't do my app cross-origin isolated(I think so because of microservices and web-socket are deployed in different domains/IPS/ports).

I am using java(spring-boot), and Angular in the front-end.

Comment: Seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/69552755/14298586

Comment: The question sounds very abstract. Please start from here: https://web.dev/coop-coep/